# Conditionally convert string to int

Tags: python, casting

In the line `data=[int(x) if x else None for x in line.replace("\n","").split(",")]` below I'd like to keep string values as string instead of throwing an exception if a value that can't be casted to int is encountered. Are there any elegant ways to do this? For instance, if you have on a given line `9327,Garlic Powder,104,13` then data would be `[9327, "Garlic Powder", 104, 13]`

Rik

```
file = open(file_path, 'r') 

# get headers
try:
    header=next(file).replace("\n","").split(",")
except:
    raise Exception("The file {} is empty.".format(file.file_path))

count = 0 # to count number of rows

# loop through file and process data
for line in file:
    try:
        data=[int(x) if x else None for x in line.replace("\n","").split(",")]
    except:
        raise Exception("The file {} contains invalid data.".format(file.file_path))
    count += 1
    for f in callback_array:
        f(header,data)
```

Comment: Is that fine if we try to cast it to an int, and based on the result, return either string or integer @Rik ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function which checks if a string can be parsed to an integer. If it can, return the integer else return the string

```
def parse(s):

    #If string can be parsed as integer, return integer
    try:
        num = int(s)
        return num
    except:
        pass
    #Else return string
    return s

line = '9327,Garlic Powder,104,13'
data=[parse(x) for x in line.replace("\n","").split(",")]

print(data)
```

The output will be

```
[9327, 'Garlic Powder', 104, 13]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep your oneliner by using `isnumeric`:

```
data=[int(x) if x and x.isnumeric() else x for x in line.replace("\n","").split(",")]
```

Comment: This won't work for strings containing negative integers e.g `-1`

Comment: Yes - I merely based on his sample data. If negative numbers are also included, should go for a function instead like yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
>>> def type_convert(var):
    if var.isnumeric():
        return int(var)
    elif isinstance(var, str):
        return var
    else:
        return None


>>> [type_convert(i) for i in a]
[9327, 'Garlic Powder', 104, 13]
>>> new = [type_check(i) for i in a]
>>> [type(n) for n in new]
[<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>]
```